# in angularjs is there a way to show a number of divs using a directive or feature of some sort?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In angularjs, is there a way to show a certain amount of a single html element like a div.  For instance I want angular to display a div 5 times:

html

```
<div ng-show="5"><p>testing</p></div>
```

I want angular to display the above div 5 times without any additional javascript, just by using an angular feature like a directive.  How would you do that in angularjs?

Comment: have you tried `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="n in new Array(5)"><p>testing</p></div>
```

This might not work, so you'll have to define an array generating function within your scope.

Like this:

```
$scope.arrayn = (n) => new Array(n);
```

then

```
<div ng-repeat="n in arrayn(5)"><p>testing</p></div>
```

Comment: thanks.  now how do i use 5 as a variable instead of hardcoding it?

Comment: @dave (he has a wrong syntax) you could try use a function that creates an array of some size: `'n in create_array(5) track by $index'`

Comment: You could create this new array in your scope and use the variable instead. I don't know angular that much so I can't get too much into it, but that's how you'd loop.

Comment: This works for vue so I assume it'll work for Angular since the notation is pretty much the same. http://jsfiddle.net/yzujvoq9/

Comment: @Phiter it evaluates with scope, so it assumes that `new` is somewhere in the controller and written as `$scope.new = function(){...}`

Comment: I see. I'll update my answer then so the function is defined in the scope.